# $ABC \le G$ if and only if $ABC=BCA$ and $BCB\subseteq ABC$ where $A$, $B$, $C$ are subgroups of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

when I was doing the group theory problems as a summer project I faced with this question I will be appreciate if you give me a hint to solve it

> Let $A$, $B$, $C$ be three subgroups of a group $G$. Then $ABC \le G$ if and only if $ABC=BCA$ and $BCB\subseteq ABC$.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Here's one part of one direction:
Assume $ABC=BCA$ and $BCB\subseteq ABC$.
Let $g,g'\in ABC$. We want to show $gg'\in ABC$. Write $g=abc$ and using $ABC=BCA$ write $g'=b'c'a'$ (of course with $a,a'\in A, b,b'\in B, c,c'\in C$). Also, as $BCB\subseteq ABC$ we can write $bcb'=a''b''c''$.
And as $b''c''c'a'\in BCA$ we can write it as $a'''b'''c'''$. With all these we obtain 
$$ gg'=abcb'c'a'=aa''b''c''c'a'=aa''a'''b'''c'''\in ABC.$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint for the other part:

Suppose $ABC \leq G$ and let $abc \in ABC$. Consider

$abc \cdot a = \bar{a} \bar{b} \bar{c}$ for some $\bar{a}, \bar{b}, \bar{c} \in ABC$ (since $ABC$ is a **subgroup**). Then we have $\bar{a}^{-1} abc = \bar{b} \bar{c} a^{-1} \in BCA$.  Note that left multiplication with a group element gives a bijective map. Thus $ABC \subseteq BCA$. The other direction works similarly. Also the assertion $BCB \subseteq ABC$ is proven with an analogous computation.